Cannot get VSCode to detect C++ compilers on WSL
Issue:
When clicking "run C/C++", some/all compilers installed fail to be detected by VSCode (Trying to use g++ and clang++ - g++ only detected on Arch WSL, none detected on Ubuntu WSL).
Steps to Reproduce (Ubuntu):

Updated and upgraded apt repository

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


Installed build-essential and clang

sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install clang


ensured proper installation

g++ -v
clang++ -v


Ran code . and installed necessary extensions (C/C++, WSL).

Created a test file, and attempted to run the file in the VSCode window by selecting "Run C/C++ File".
The result: Neither g++ nor clang++ appear in the detection window.



I've looked up issues with VSCode's task list detection and attempted to modify some of the settings in Features > Tasks - I could not find any useful links nor could resolve the issue through trial and error.

If you look under /usr/bin, do you have a gcc or g++ directory installed?

I can recommend this extension for debugging C++ in VSCode.

@AndréLehto They aren't directories, but I have binary files for gcc and g++ in /usr/bin.
